# Prove that $s$ is constant $\mu$-almost everywhere if $s$ is upper semicontinuous

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, functional-analysis, semicontinuous-functions

Let $f:(X, d)\to (X, d)$ be a homeomorphism on compact metric space $(X, d)$. We define a new metric $d_\infty$ on $X$ by $d_\infty(x, y)= \sup_{n\in\mathbb{Z}}d(f^n(x), f^n(y))$, and 
$s(x)=\inf \{d_\infty-diam(U): x\in U \text{ open }\}$.

In a paper author claim that $s$ is upper-semicontinuous and invariant function, hence it is constant $\mu$-almost everywhere.

My attempt: By definition of $s(x)$, for every $\epsilon>0$, there is open set $U$ of $x$ such that $d_\infty -diam(U)<s(x)+\epsilon$, hence for every $y\in U$, $s(y)\leq d_\infty-diam(U)<s(x)+\epsilon$, hence $s$ is upper semicontinuous. Also since $d_\infty-diam (f(U))= d_\infty-diam(U)$, the function $s$ is invariant.

But it is not clear for me the following statement:
"it is constant $\mu$-almost everywhere"?

Please help me to know it.

Comment: Surely it's not true that an upper semi/continuous function which is invariant under some homeomorphism $f$ is automatically constant a.e.: For instance, say $s$ were on the nose continuous and $f$ were the identity. You should know something more? Or... what's the measure $\mu$? I'd assume it was just some appropriate Hausdorff measure on $(X,d)$.

Comment: It is quite easy to show that $s(x)=s(f(x))$ but, as mentioned in above comment, you have nor provided enough information to draw the final conclusion .

Comment: @WoolierThanThou, thanks. Yes, $f$ admits an ergodic measure of full support which the set of all points $x\in X$ with $s(x)>0$ has positive measure.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy, Thanks. By above assumption, author implies that there is $c>0$ such that $s^{-1}(c)$ is dense. If we replace above assumption with " there is $x\in X$ such that $\overline{\{f^n(x)\}_{n\in\mathbb{Z}}}=X$, can we say that there is $c>0$ such that $s^{-1}(c)$ is dense?. $f^n=f\circ f\circ \ldots f$, (n-times)